# Qt, how to simulate user clicks in input type=file

Tags: jquery, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebview

My question in short: I want to upload images to a website automatically. However, I couldn't simulate input type=file.

I have the following input element in a webpage.

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/server/images/e1b2d17b7b7eccef21a0a0ba1756d35c/upload/" multiple="">
```

I know that it is disabled due to security reasons to simulate this element using JS or JQuery. That's fine. However, I load the page into my QWebElement and I want to upload images automatically by simulating the necessary mouse clicks. I have managed to click to the upload button but I can't simulate typing any folder name or file name into the opened Dialog Box. I think I need to focus on the Dialog Box but couldn't do it. Could anyone guide me a bit?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look into selenium how it is doing it, although it is python, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send mouse click event to input point coordinates. Here is PyQt code to do it.

```
# We need to scroll our window, to make input "visible" and get it's coordinates
el_pos = el.geometry().center()  # el - QWebElement points to input
self._page.mainFrame().setScrollPosition(el_pos)  # self._page - QWebPage
scr_pos = self._page.mainFrame().scrollPosition()
point_to_click = el_pos - scr_pos

# Create click on coordinates
press = QMouseEvent(QMouseEvent.MouseButtonPress, point_to_click, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
release = QMouseEvent(QMouseEvent.MouseButtonRelease, point_to_click, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.LeftButton, Qt.NoModifier)
QApplication.postEvent(self._handler, press)  # self._handler - QWebView
QApplication.postEvent(self._handler, release)
```

After choose file dialog "opened", Qt calls [QWebPage.chooseFile()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebpage.html#chooseFile) function to get file name, that should be choosen. We need to reimplement this method in out QWebPage:

```
class WebPage(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.file_name = 'test.png'  # file name we want to be choosed

    def chooseFile(self, frame, suggested_file):
        return self.file_name  # file will be choosen after click on input type=file
```

**Update:**

And one more thing. In case input allow to select **multiple files**, reimplementing QWebPage.chooseFile() wouldn't work. To handle this, you should add support of [QWebPage::ChooseMultipleFilesExtension](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#Extension-enum). Here is [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558873/python-pyqt4-webkit-how-to-set-value-of-inputtype-file-multiple/22573260#22573260) how to do it.